# Saving MultiDimensional Arrays to Storage

Tags: swift, core-data, multidimensional-array, save, plist

I am building a puzzle in Swift that I would like to store a multiDimensional  Array to storage.  I have a number of options for this including NSDefaults, Core, Plists, among others.  I know that if I do this in NSDefaults that I am essentially bringing the multiDimensional array back out and saving it each time I make a change.  This could be disk intensive.

The MultiDimensional Array would be: [30x20] in size.  Any recommendations on how best to store this.

I've tried looking at a number of guides and while NSDefaults looks to be the easiest I am concerned about the performance (and I'd like to learn how to do it the right way).

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.  I was able to get Core working, but nothing this complex.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually tried a number of ways including core data, plists, sqlite, and ultimately ended up using Realm.  It was much easier than the others and is really fast.  I highly recommend it if you're getting stuck on this like I was:

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

I am actually removing all of my plists in favor of Realm at this point due to the ease of use and simple view.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Declare properties as show in above image & set custom Class as `Array<Array<Any>>` in Attributes model:

Declare properties in CoreDataProperties class like:
  `@NSManaged public var routes: Array<Array<Any>> //`

**Usages:**

While using initialise properties like:

`<your_rroperty_name> =  obj["routes"] as? [[String]] ?? [[]]`